# Log4J2: clear older log files after rollover

Tags: log4j2

I have been using log4j2 recently and I have encountered a problem. When a rollover occurs, active log file keeps its logs. Is is possible to clear log file so that the rolled file will keep only the logs for the time period that they have specified in name?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking for an additional feature for the RolloverFileAppender. This feature would allow you to specify a time period. At each rollover, the RolloverFileAppender would not only roll over the current log file, but would also check previously rolled over files and would delete those previously rolled over files that are older than the specified time period.

Is this what you are asking? No such feature currently exists, but there is an outstanding feature request here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-524
You may want to vote for this issue or add a comment so that the team is aware there are more users interested in this feature.

---

Update January 2016: The above feature has been implemented.

Since 2.5, Log4j supports a [custom Delete action](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover) that is executed on every rollover.

You can control which files are deleted by any combination of:

1. Name (matching a [glob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)) or a [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html))
2. [Age](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/action/Duration.html#parseCharSequence) ("delete if 14 days old or older")
3. Count ("keep only the most recent 3")
4. Size ("keep only the most recent files up to 500MB")

Users who need even more fine-grained control over which files to delete can specify a script condition using any supported JSR-223 scripting language.

Please check out the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover), it has three full examples that may be useful.

For your question, this snippet may work:

```
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    <!--
      * only files in the log folder, no sub folders
      * only rolled over log files (name match)
      * only files 30 days old or older
    -->
    <Delete basePath="rolledoverlogs" maxDepth="1">
      <IfFileName glob="my-log*.log.gz" />
      <IfLastModified age="30d" />
    </Delete>
  </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
```

Finally, be careful! There is no way to recover files deleted this way. :-)

Comment: Not exactly. What i want is to have, after rollover, empty log file to which logs are logged.